# Is it doable and appropriate to use ScalaCheck directly in applications?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I'm wondering if it's doable and appropriate to use ScalaCheck directly in applications as oppose to using it only in tests. I haven't read it thoroughly. But it seems to me that `Gen`'s `doApply()` is `private[scalacheck]` so that those generators can't be used directly to get underlying values.

Comment: You mean like pythons doctest (or the Erlang thing) ?

Comment: And what do you want to achieve with this? Some data validation?

Comment: I want to produce some junk data with different patterns. Thought ScalaCheck's rich set of combinators can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed you can. Here's an example from the ScalaCheck book for creating a password-like generator, and how to use it:

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen

val genString = for {
             c1 <- Gen.numChar
             c2 <- Gen.alphaUpperChar
             c3 <- Gen.alphaLowerChar
             c4 <- Gen.alphaChar
             c5 <- Gen.alphaNumChar
           } yield List(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5).mkString

scala> genString.sample
res0: Option[String] = Some(7Okpt)

scala> genString.sample
res1: Option[String] = Some(6WwTg)
```